# Boot toe wiggles in frame touring binding - is this ok?

Tags: alpine-touring

I just got my first set of frame touring bindings (I have not toured before, but want to start).  I am using my alpine boots with Tyrolia Aambition (10 and 13 models that are both frame touring bindings).  The toe of my boot wiggles a bit in the bindings.  Is this ok?  Or is there a mistake in the installation?  (with my alpine boots and bindings, the toe is always very solid and fixed...).

Comment: Is it the binding wiggling on the ski, or the boot in the binding? If it's the binding wiggling, you may want to use something like quiver killers to strengthen the connection between ski and binding (https://quiverkiller.com/).